# Best way to pad section of this string with 0s

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is 2 examples of what the string currently look like:

```
   6731-121-1
   9552-3-1
```

This is what I want to pad them to look like

```
   0006731-121-1
   0009552-003-1
```

So I want them to be padded with 7 zeroes before the first '-' then 3 zeroes between the first and second '-'

What would be the best way to accomplish this in SQL SELECT statement.

```
 SELECT   RIGHT('0000000'
               + ISNULL(
                           LEFT(OE.exception_id, CHARINDEX('-', OE.exception_id)
                                                 - 1) ,
                           ''
                       ) ,7) + '-'
         + SUBSTRING(OE.exception_id, CHARINDEX('-', ( OE.exception_id )), 10) exception_id
```

Comment: I was able to get the first part accomplished.... not sure if it's best practice. It was the second padding between the '-' that I was unsure of. Added first attempt to question

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: Is it always 3 parts?

Comment: Yes. Always 3 parts

Comment: Then I would go with John Cappelletti's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ParseName() could be an option here

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([YourCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('6731-121-1')
,('9552-3-1')

Select *
      ,NewVal = right('0000000'+parsename(replace(YourCol,'-','.'),3),7)
               +'-'
               +right('000'+parsename(replace(YourCol,'-','.'),2),3)
               +'-'
               +parsename(replace(YourCol,'-','.'),1)
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
YourCol     NewVal
6731-121-1  0006731-121-1
9552-3-1    0009552-003-1
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, just not fast enough :-)

Comment: I've never seen `PARSENAME()` being used like this, but I kind of like the idea. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I'm a big fan of copy and paste  :)

Comment: I've never seen PARASENAME() in general. So thank you again for sharing. TIL

Comment: `PARSENAME()` is awesome, but I believe it is only SQL2012+, correct?

Comment: @Shawn Actually 2008 I believe it was undocumented.

Comment: And it can be used for up to 4 delimited positions. It's an awesome function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Cool. didn't realize it was undocumented in 2008. That's very good to know.

Answer (score 1):

In situations with more than 3 periods

Example: **'1.2.3.4.5'**

Or any value is empty

3 examples: **'1..3'**, **'1.2.3.'**, **'.2'**

Parsename will return null for all values. You will need to split the column using a different method.

Here is an alternative to parsename:

```
DECLARE @table table(col varchar(100))
INSERT @table values('6731-121-1'),('9552-3-1')

SELECT 
  col,
  REPLICATE('0', 8-x) + STUFF(col, x+1, 0,REPLICATE('0', 4 - (y-x))) newcol
FROM @table
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT CHARINDEX('-', col) x) x
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT CHARINDEX('-', col + '-', x+1) y) y

col         newcol
6731-121-1  0006731-121-1
9552-3-1    0009552-003-1
```